# What does "Select same appearance" do?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

In Illustrator, there is a way to select objects based on shared attributes such as Fill Color or Stroke Color. I've been using this feature often.

However, I am puzzled by the option to select objects based on "Appearance". Whenever I try this feature, all the objects in the Artboard get selected and the Fill and Stroke color indicators show a "?".

[image]

***What does "Select Same Appearance" do exactly?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches *everything*, meaning all properties have to be the same.

If you open the *Appearance Panel* (**Window → Appearance** or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>), all items in that panel have to be the same between both(+) paths.

If you apply a transform effect to one object, it will not pick up as "Same Appearance" since the effect shows up in the panel:

[image]

If they **do** have different properties, when you select it, it will come up as "*Mixed Appearances*"

[image]